# Django signals doesn't work when creating model instance implicitly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals, django-inheritance

I can't find out why my `signal` does not work when the instance (of proxy model) is created implicitely by third app.

I use a third party app `Django-Quiz` in my project. There is a model called `Sitting`. Since I want to see the table in admin, I had to create a `proxy` model `QuizSittingProxy`, to be able to set `__str__` and `__unicode__` methods for `Sitting`.

Each time when `User` takes a quiz, the new `Sitting` object is created. Respectively `QuizSittingProxy` object is created too.

```
class QuizSittingProxy(Sitting):
    """
    Holds information about taken Language Tests (in admin)
    """
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}, score: {}'.format(self.user.username, self.quiz.title, self.current_score)
```

I want to assign result of the quiz to current `User` so I've created a `signal`.

The problem is, that this `signal` works only if I create a `QuizSittingProxy` object manually in admin.

Worth to say that it is created everytime `User` takes a quiz.

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=QuizSittingProxy)
def assign_level(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print 'QUIZSITTING POST SAVE'
    # user = instance.user
    # quiz = instance.quiz
    # score = len(instance.user_answers.keys()) / instance.current_score
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Could you use `sender=Sitting` instead?

Comment: what exactly does QuizSittingProxy do? Cant you just put that __str__ into Sitting itself?